# Command line arguments are not in order

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am using Common-CLI api to display help to the command. Following function displays help of the command.

```
public static void printHelp(final Options options, final int width, final String cmdLineSyntax,
        final String header, final String footer, final int leftPad, final int descPad, final boolean autoUsage,
        final OutputStream out) {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
    final HelpFormatter helpFormatter = new HelpFormatter();
    helpFormatter.printHelp(writer, width, cmdLineSyntax, header, options, leftPad, descPad, footer, autoUsage);
    writer.flush();
}
```

I added options in the following order.

```
Option option1 = Option.builder("A").longOpt("almost-all").desc("do not list implied . and ..").hasArg(false)
                .build();

        Option option2 = Option.builder("b").longOpt("block-size").argName("SIZE> <CAPACITY> <LINE").numberOfArgs(3)
                .desc("use SIZE-byte blocks").hasArg(true).build();

        Option option3 = Option.builder("c")
                .desc("with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information) with -l:show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort by ctime")
                .hasArg(false).build();

        Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption(option1);
        options.addOption(option2);
        options.addOption(Option.builder().longOpt("escape").desc("print octal escapes for nongraphic characters")
                .hasArg(false).build());

        options.addOption(option3);
```

When I call the printHelp function on options object, I am getting following output.

```
usage: ls [-A] [-b <SIZE> <CAPACITY> <LINE>] [-c] [--escape]
     -A,--almost-all                              do not list implied . and ..
     -b,--block-size <SIZE> <CAPACITY> <LINE>     use SIZE-byte blocks
     -c                                           with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last
                                                  modification of file status information) with
                                                  -l:show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort by
                                                  ctime
        --escape                                  print octal escapes for nongraphic characters
```

But I am expecting in following way.

```
usage: ls [-A] [-b <SIZE> <CAPACITY> <LINE>] [-c] [--escape]
     -A,--almost-all                              do not list implied . and ..
     -b,--block-size <SIZE> <CAPACITY> <LINE>     use SIZE-byte blocks
        --escape                                  print octal escapes for nongraphic characters
     -c                                           with -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last
                                                  modification of file status information) with
                                                  -l:show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort by
                                                  ctime
```

Can any one tell me, how can I get the expected output?

Comment: I am not familiar with "apache-commons-cli" but it seems the order of creating the options is relevant for the print order. So you have to create the last option one step above.

Comment: I am adding the options in the order to options object.

Comment: Yes, but you are creating them in another order than you are putting it into the options object. The answer explains this obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The order of creation of option objects doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html) is what you are looking for.

> public void setOptionComparator(Comparator comparator) Set the
>   comparator used to sort the options when they output in help text.
>   Passing in a null comparator will keep the options in the order they
>   were declared. Parameters: comparator - the Comparator to use for
>   sorting the options

Ref: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/HelpFormatter.html